# Move Mysites with OneDrive on Premises

Tags: 2013, migration, onedrive

I have one farm which has a **MySite** for every user, each users desktop is then set up to use **OneDrive** for Business on the **Mysite**.

I have begun testing a migration technique to get all the user profile and Mysites to a new SharePoint 2013 (fresh build) For testing purposes I am using my own MySite and completing the below:

- Setup new 2013 Farm
- Backup and Restore:

  - Managed Metadata Database
  - Profiles Database
  - Profiles Social Database
  - Profiles Sync Database
- Create new Managed Metadata Service using existing Database
- Create new User Profile Service using existing Database
- Move my MySite into a new content database (move-spsite)
- Detach Content Database from Current farm
- Attach Content Database to new farm

At this point everything looks like it works, I can browse the site in the new farm and user profile service all looks good.

I set a hosts entry on my desktop to point at the new **WFE** of the new farm for my `profiles.com.au` but **OneDrive** can no longer connect to the library and even if I remove it and try to start a new sync it still cannot connect

Comment: any error, check uls logs and Event log?

Comment: I wasn't seeing anything, I left it overnight and came back to it this morning and now it works so I wonder if there was a job which needed to run after the database attach (different versions, maybe an upgrade?) or when the timer jobs and IIS recycled that caused it, I will investigate today.